# Kafka min.insync.replicas < replication.factor

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Suppose I have a cluster with 3 kafka brokers. I set:

```
min.insync.replicas=2
default.replication.factor=3
```

- All brokers are up, ISR is fine, I get a message where `ack=all`. Since `ISR=2`, two copies of the message are for sure stored. 1) Will one more copy (because replication=3) be made in the background? 2) If it fails - it does not matter, correct? Cluster health is just fine.
- One broker is down, `ISR=2` can be maintained and the message is saved to two brokers. After some time that broker that was down comes up again. 3) Since replication=3, will it try to catch up with the others in the back-ground?

I am trying to figure out of a *practical* example where setting replication factor to be bigger than ISR would make sense. A real example I could "touch" and understand. If this is a duplicate, please refer me to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one replica is made in the background.

Yes, the broker will catch up all out of sync replicas upon restarts.

If you ever have in-sync replicas <= replication factor, then you cannot lose any brokers more than the difference between the values (due to maintenance or failure). Therefore, replication factor should always be greater

Comment: shouldn't `in-sync replicas <= replication factor` be in reverse?

Comment: No. I said, if it's setup that way, you cannot lose brokers. Also replication factor can never be less than replicas

Comment: The verbiage here is miss-leading, imo. "If you ever have in-sync replicas <= replication factor, then you cannot lose any brokers". You are using `<=`, which is "less or equal" in pure math, which means you are saying "If ISR < RF, you cannot lose any brokers", only to later say : "Therefore, replication factor should always be greater", which is already the exact same condition outlined in the previous statement: "ISR < RF". So maybe you meant `=` instead of `<=`?

Comment: No. I mean less than or equal to. You don't need to explain what I typed. I edited to clarify my statement

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is absolutely correct, but it took me quite a while to figure out. imho, this is somehow subtle and though my understanding might be a little incorrect here and there, it helped to build a mental model of what is going on.

Suppose I have a cluster of 3 brokers :

```
[a, b, c]  ->  brokers
[a, b]     -> ISR
[a, b, c]  -> RF
```

How many brokers can I tolerate to be down? The answer is 1.

- If lose broker "c", ISR can still be satisfied and the cluster will work just fine.
- If I lose broker "a" (the explanation is the same if I lost "b"), a rebalance has to happen. zookeeper will ask what brokers were in-sync (who satisfied RF) *before* I lost one from the ISR. Well, there were 3 of them part of RF = a, b, c. Since I lost "a", there are two left now that are in sync: "b" and "c". A leader election has to happen and the ISR will be satisfied with "b" and "c".
- This means that I can lose *any* one broker from the cluster and still work fine. It might be trivial here, but the next example is not so much, imho.

---

Suppose I have a (artificial example) cluster with 5 brokers:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]  -> brokers
[a, b]           -> ISR
[a, b, c]        -> RF
```

How many brokers can I tolerate as being down now? Initially I thought 2, but that can't be correct.

- If I lose "d" and "e", it's simple, the cluster will continue to work just fine.
- If lose "a" and "b", in theory a rebalance has to happen. But what brokers were part of RF before I lost "a" and "b" or which brokers were in-sync? [a, b, c]. There is no way to satisfy ISR if two of those brokers are down.
- This means that I can't tolerate *any* two brokers being down, which means this set-up is not really fault tolerant with *any* 2 brokers down.
- It can only be tolerant with two brokers down if my set-up is different:

  ```
  5 -> brokers
  3 -> ISR
  5 -> RF
  ```

---

And this is where the other answer is correct and makes total sense:

> If you ever have in-sync replicas <= replication factor, then you cannot lose any brokers more than the difference between the values